# Iterating through Radio Buttons in Windows Forms/VC++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, radio-button, iteration

I have 10 Radio Buttons in a Windows Form with design names `temp1RadioButton`to `temp10RadioButton` and appearance names `temp1` to `temp10`. I want to iterate through all of them and change each of their appearance name. How can this be achieved in VC++? Please note, that I have created them in drag and drop style. Moreover, all I have is the natively generated Windows Forms code, so I am not putting it here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to Windows Forms. Is your app written in C++ or managed extension of C++?